# Django __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am getting `__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)` error at edit  `Product` Model object

[image]

## Product Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ProductName = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    Price = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=9.99)
    Tax = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0.0)
    StoreId = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    RelatedStore = models.ForeignKey(Store, blank=True, null=True)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                blank=True, null=True,
                                default='No Specific Category')
    ProductImage = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    Features = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ProductSize = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=3)
    FavoriteField = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    Active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ProductName

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProductName
```

Any helpful answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use Pascal case while defining fields. use lower case or Camel case

Comment: I'd say, that your `{{ field.field }}` does not call `Product.__str__`. The latter should never return `None`, since you don't have `null=True` in your model field. Add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to your `__str__` method, then the browser _should_ hang and the console running runserver should open a debug prompt, _if_ the method is called - which it very probably won't

Comment: alternatively, go into `./manage.py shell`, import Product from Products.models, find the product and explicitly call the str method with `Product.objects.get(pk=400).__str__()`

Comment: @llja `Product.objects.get(pk=400).__str__()` returns excepted result ProductName

Comment: Please show your `RelatedStore` model and `__str__` method. Since you are using Python 3, you can remove `__unicode__`.

Comment: Please change your naming conventions and follow python best practices for naming conventions.

Answer (score 11):

you can try:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.ProductName) if self.ProductName else ''
```

Answer (score 6):

I little late but change the return as follows:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.ProductName)
```

Comment: it worked..!!  @Jorge López How this is making difference as the charfield itself a string already why we are required to convert it to string again

Comment: Hi @ivardu, python complaints about NoneType when a value is None so in order to represent you have to convert to string, I'm not completely sure but I believe that is the reason.

Answer (score 3):

`__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)`

is returned when the model you are accessing OR **other models related** to it is / are returning an `int` value on the def `__str__` function. Should you be returning an int, be sure to parse the value to a String option.

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on Foregienkey :

```
 RelatedStore = models.ForeignKey(Store, blank=True, null=True)

#edit or delete this:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProductName
```

or else check the Store class there will be some

```
def_str_(self):
 return self.something
```

then it will work fine , I know i am late but that worked for me !!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, just make sure that the table (or the model) does not return and does not contain any attribute (or foreign key) whose the table / model returns an integer.
You can use this for those attribute if you want to return primary key:

```py
def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.pk))
```

In your case, make sure that the **RelatedStore** class / model / table returns a string.