# I am following a course to have an E-commerce Shop with Django. Problem: Exception Value:__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Tags: django

I am following a course to have an E-commerce Shop with Django. I am having this error when I am trying to see the **Order** on the Django Admin: Exception Value:**str** returned non-string (type NoneType) pointing out the line 19 of admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 19 {{ field.field }}

I know that the problem is with the Customer variable in the Order class, but I do not know how to get the customer from the Customer class to put it on my Order class. This is my code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import reverse


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(user, max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

[...]

class Order(models.Model):
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
        transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

Comment: `name` can be `NULL` so `None`, therefore it does not always return a string.

Comment: Please Share the code for admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47263135/11979793